# django-rest-framework ModelSerializer fields whose names are invalid Python identifiers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

If I have a serializer thus:

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    content = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
```

then the dictionary returned by `serializer.data` will have keys `"email"` and `"content"`.

But I need to include fields whose names are not valid Python identifiers:

- `"type"`
- `"@context"`

Is there an idiomatic way of doing this?

Comment: You can try setting them in get_fields method,  then you can use just strings.

Comment: Is this just for `list` and `retrieve`, or do those fields need to handle write access (deserialization) too?

Comment: Read-only access. Thank you: I should have made that clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to override `to_representation()` method in `CommentSerializer` as,

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    type = serializers.EmailField()
    content = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        return_data = {}
        return_data.update({"type": data['type'], "@context": data['content']})
        return return_data
```

**EX:**

```
In [2]: mydata = {"type": "myemail@gmail.com","content": "some content"}

In [3]: comment = CommentSerializer(data=mydata)

In [4]: comment.is_valid(True)
Out[4]: True

In [5]: comment.data
Out[5]: {'type': 'myemail@gmail.com', '@context': 'some content'}
```